# jQTouch loading remote data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqtouch

I'm using jQTouch which is an implementation of jQuery with some extra stuff for mobile devices.  I have a div with id=testinner.
When I use this code, it works fine from a local file:

```
$("#testinner").load("test.html");
```

But if I test with a remote file, nothing loads

```
$("#testinner").load("http://www.google.com");
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Cross-domain restrictions exist, even for jQtouch applications. What you are doing is breaking that rule by trying to request a page that is outside of the current domain name.

If you want to access external data, it will have to support JSON-P(JSON with a callback) or it will need to exist on the same server your code sits on.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to make an ajax call which is forbidden by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If you want to fetch some data from a different domain, you have to use [JSON-P](http://quotesondesign.com/api/3.0/api-3.0.json?callback=my_function)

```
 $.getJSON('http://www.google.com', function(data) {
 });
```

Comment: Its a hard call isn't it? if you edit the OP's post to make it readable, you risk someone else answering the question first :)

Comment: @dcneiner: yep especially if the OP really poorly formated the question but sometimes SO is more about quality of answer then being the first!

Comment: This URL might be better, since it supports JSON-P: `quotesondesign.com/api/3.0/api-3.0.json?callback=my_function`